# Trace bootup time on Windows 7 x64 Enterprise edition

Tags: windows-7, boot

How can I trace the bootup time on Windows 7 64 bit? Or is there another tool? there used to a tool in the past called bootvis.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, just gauge the time taken to boot, or see how long each part of the boot takes?

Comment: see how long each part of the boot takes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I'm refering to this [tutorial](http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-tips-tutorials-articles/30384-how-time-boot-perform-boot-trace-windows-microsoft-windows-7-sdk.html)